# Array-based implementation of the list interface

Tags: java, arrays, list, object, interface

I am looking at some example code on Listinterface and the implementation of it using array. I don't understand the instance variable `private Object items[];  // an array of list items` So is it an object called items, which is an array? why doesn't it just say private array items[] ? 
Also about the constructor `items = new Object[MAX_LIST];`does it initalise an array named item? The code is attached below. Many thanks for your help!

```
public interface ListInterface {
 public boolean isEmpty();
  public int size();
  public void add(int index, Object item) 
              throws ListIndexOutOfBoundsException,
                     ListException;
  public Object get(int index) 
              throws ListIndexOutOfBoundsException;
  public void remove(int index) 
              throws ListIndexOutOfBoundsException;
  public void removeAll();
  } 

public class ListArrayBased implements ListInterface {



private static final int MAX_LIST = 90;
  private Object items[];  // an array of list items
  private int numItems;  // number of items in list
```

Comment: You should probably start reading at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, `private Object items[];` is exactly equivalent to `private Object[] items;` -- it's just different way of writing an array of `Object` called `items`.

Comment: but the add method uses a parameter type Object, name item. Is it not an object, which is an array named item?

Answer (score 0):

Object is a Generic. It can be any object including String, Integer, etc.. So here you are creating an Array of the type Object, with the size mentioned.

Better go through Oracle Java Tutorials about Arrays.